# ArcGIS Near equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: attribute-joins, mysql, proximity

I am trying to replicate a process in MySQL that I have had been through in ArcGIS thereby using MySQL to set up an automated system for extracting future climate predictions from downscaled data to farm. The downscaled data frustratingly cuts off some key growing areas. To get approximate local data in ArcGIS I converted the climate data to grid points, then used the NEAR function to return a near distance and FID. I then joined attributes from the climate data to the farm data by the table Near FID.

In mySQL they do not have a NEAR function but a distance once, but I do not think this returns an FID and creates a value for all points not just the closest one? Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Farms in a region missing climate projection data]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, you appear to have provided some information about one problem, but then asked a different question. Please [Edit] the question to contain enough information on your exact process, and if you choose to ask about implementing it in MySQL, what you have tried with that software.

Comment: I have now edited it.